# Questions about Unity3d should automatically get C# syntax-highlighting

Tags: discussion, feature-request, syntax-highlighting

[Unity3d](https://unity3d.com/) uses (almost) only C# as the main programming language.

However lots of questions about [`[Unity3d]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unity3d/info) in my opinion don't really need / should maybe not be tagged [`[c#]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info), because they refer to a Unity3d API specific problem and are actually not about C# in general. (And also because the available C#/.NET version in Unity is often version specific.)

---

So until now I use

```
<!-- language: lang-c# -->
```

or

```
<!-- language-all: lang-c# -->
```

on almost all Unity3d questions and don't tag them `[c#]`.

---

**I therefore think the syntax-highlighting for questions tagged `[unity3d]` should automatically be set to `c#` - Or should I tag all `[unity3d]` questions also `[c#]`?**

Comment: you say almost always but what should someone do when they are posting with a different language?

Comment: @JoeW than you can still change it manually like how do it now all the time `<!-- language: lang-XY -->`. Or - I honestly don't know what happens for multiple language tags but - I'ld expect that if you add additional language tags the parser tries to recognize the correct one?

Comment: Hm, Unity is not strictly tied to C# though. In the recent past it also targeted Javascript, but that has been discontinued so at this moment in time it is mostly C# oriented. Who knows what will be true tomorrow. IMO, a language tag is a better solution.

Comment: Unit3D has 2 programming langs supported Javascript in older version which might still be used or C# the now default the that means the language tag is needed so developers know which one they are helping with like I can support C# less than I can support Javascript in Unity3D. older versions might still be used by people who have paid for Pro of an older version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We are reluctant to add language highlighting hints to non-language tags, because it can cause all sorts of unexpected behavior and general breakage.

I don't think it's appropriate in this case, for basically the same [reasons that Gimby already pointed out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380910/questions-about-unity3d-should-automatically-get-c-syntax-highlithing#comment675110_380910). Unity3D is not, by design, a strictly C#-specific API. It can be used from other languages, including JavaScript, Boo, and F#.

Even if it *mostly* targets C#, that's not enough to introduce a language highlighting hint.

There is no drawback to simply applying a language tag to the question. If there's C# code, then a [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) tag is quite appropriate. You'll get the appropriate syntax highlighting for free.

Anyone who wants to answer C# questions that are *not* about Unity3D can just filter out that tag.

Comment: Maybe lang-default can be considered but adding the language specific tag is much cleaner.

Comment: lang-default could still introduce clashes. Unity3D is a more popular tag than, say, Boo. I don't see the advantage. @rene

Comment: Yeah, agree, it was more a suggestion in case lots of followers in that tag insist on having an highlighter enabled. I'm not familiar with Boo's syntax but I expect most people will not notice the difference between lang-default vs lang-csharp or lang-js

Comment: @CodyGray yeah sounds reasonable. Just a question: Let's say a question about unity3d is not tagged c# and doesn't provide code (though it should ofcourse) - however I answer it providing c# code. should I rather add the `<!-- language` comment or tag the question c#?

Comment: If the question isn’t about C#, then it shouldn’t have the tag. Your choice of language to demonstrate the use of the library is incidental. Just add the formatting hint to your post. @der

Comment: If a question isn't about a programming problem with Unity3d, should it even be considered for the site? How should we distinguish between a UI specific problem with Unity3d and a language-choice related one? Send them to [gamedev.se] all the time? Require a language tag if Unity3d tag is selected?

Comment: You should make the distinction by reading the question, @Eliasar. If it's not programming-related, it's likely off-topic for Stack Overflow and should be closed. However, do keep in mind that tools/libraries commonly used by programmers *are* on-topic here, so problems with a Unity3D UI are going to be on-topic here, even if the question doesn't need to contain any code.

Comment: I disagree.  Unity dropped support for Javascript in 2017.   The Unity3d API has different idioms around async programming, eventing, serialization, and coroutines.   This makes it annoying when askers add the C# tag to get C# syntax hilighting, and a C# expert gives an answer that doesn't work in Unity, and the (wrong) answer gets upvotes from other C# tag watchers.

Comment: Can this be looked at again? Considering Unity has now fully dropped support for languages outside of C# (Boo, UnityScript)? And although yes, F# *can* be used in Unity it is not an out of the box native support. IMO there is a drawback to having to add the C# tag, it creates an unnecessary bump, and requires people to do edits that could be prevented.

Comment: @CodyGray "now" that Unity fully dropped other language supports except for `c#` (a while ago) .. would you still stick to this or would we have to reconsider? ;)

Comment: Perhaps this may not be appropriate, but when facing [a question with only the unity tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76582219/how-to-roll-a-2d-square-sprite-in-forward-and-backward/76585965#76585965), you have 3 options: 1. Add a c# tag, 2. Specify a language, 3. Use the default synatx highlighting. Obviously, the 3rd one is the most convenient and can provide higher readability to the code in the first place.